# iOS swift Charts library: How to retrieve data item on graph selection?

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I have a graph and when I touch it.  It successfully highlights our graph, but I cannot seem to retrieve the specific datapoint that is being selected.

To be even more specific I am using a horizontal bar graph such that it is a segmented bar graph.  This is our datatype used to create the bar graph is:

```
    updateGraph(list: Array<Double>) {
            let dataEntries = [BarChartDataEntry(x: 0.0, yValues: list)]

let barChartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "")

    let colorValues = colorList.map( { $0.color })
    barChartDataSet.colors = colorValues//ChartColorTemplates.material()

    let labelValues = nameList.map( { $0.name })
    barChartDataSet.stackLabels = labelValues

    let barChartData = BarChartData(dataSet: barChartDataSet)
    barChartData.setValueFont(UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0))
    barChart.data = barChartData
}
```

Now when I select a specific part of this graph, I can successfully get chartValueSelected to fire, however it returns no useful data that can identify the specific list index being selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an h our or so of reading the API docs and messing around with things it appears that the function `chartValueSelected` gives access to a chart `highlight` which you can extract the data index path out of using `highlight.stackIndex`.

very frustrating variable naming by charts... `stackIndex` is very counter intuitive, but alas solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this library, but from reading the source, it seems like the `ChartViewDelegate.chartValueSelected` method should have a parameter `dataEntry: DataEntry` which should refer to the selected entry. Is your `chartValueSelected` method being called? Can you update your question with its contents?